# Invoking "make -j4 -4" in melodic failed

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the error. Thanks for your help. I am running on Ubuntu 18.04

```
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/tests/simulation_ws/build"
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/tests/simulation_ws/build"
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ControllerState
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RC
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeightCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Supply
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PositionXYCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ThrustCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RuddersCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawRC
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorStatus
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawMagnetic
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_YawrateCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AttitudeCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Altitude
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Altimeter
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawImu
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Compass
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelocityXYCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeadingCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorPWM
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelocityZCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ServoCommand
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CommandTrajectory
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CommandRateThrust
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorSpeed
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CommandRollPitchYawrateThrust
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CommandMotorSpeed
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CommandVelocityTrajectory
[  0%] Built target _mav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_CommandAttitudeThrust
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_WayPointArray
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PlannerService
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PlanningResponse
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Octomap
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_WaypointType
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_WayPoint
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _planning_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_OctomapScan
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_adc_data_frame
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_demo
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_perf
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_detect
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_RecordEnable
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_magneto
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector31
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_rc_references
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_euler_angles
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wifi
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pressure_raw
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_of
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_gyros_offsets
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_LedAnim
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_kalman_pressure
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_video_stream
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_phys_measures
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix33
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector21
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_altitude
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wind_speed
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_games
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_raw_measures
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_raw
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_FlightAnim
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_time
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_zimmu_3000
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pwm
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_Navdata
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_CamSelect
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_trims
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_hdvideo_stream
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_watchdog
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_trackers_send
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_references
[  0%] Performing update step for 'ardronelib'
[  1%] Building CXX object tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp.o
[  1%] Performing configure step for 'ardronelib'
No configure
[  1%] Built target _cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins_generate_messages_check_deps_SetBias
[  2%] Performing build step for 'ardronelib'
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
[  2%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Libs already extracted
Building target static
[  2%] Built target test_trajectory
Scanning dependencies of target diffdrive_plugin_6w
Architecture x86_64 is already built
Creating universal static lib file from architectures x86_64
Build done.
Building ARDroneTool/Lib
[  3%] Building CXX object tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o
cc VP_Stages/vp_stages_configs.c
In file included from ..//VP_Stages/vp_stages_configs.c:19:0:
../VP_Stages/vp_stages_o_sdl.h:33:10: fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
generic.makefile:232: recipe for target '../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/sdk_PROD_MODE_vlib_Linux_4.4.0-18362-Microsoft_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_7.4.0/VP_Stages/vp_stages_configs.o' failed
make[8]: *** [../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/sdk_PROD_MODE_vlib_Linux_4.4.0-18362-Microsoft_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_7.4.0/VP_Stages/vp_stages_configs.o] Error 1
sdk.makefile:253: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[7]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'build_sdk' failed
make[6]: *** [build_sdk] Error 2
Makefile:170: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[5]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:84: recipe for target 'build_libs' failed
make[4]: *** [build_libs] Error 2
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
tum_ardrone_sim/ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target '/tests/simulation_ws/devel/src/ardronelib-stamp/ardronelib-build' failed
make[2]: *** [/tests/simulation_ws/devel/src/ardronelib-stamp/ardronelib-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4172: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/ardrone_autonomy/CMakeFiles/ardronelib.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_gps.h:38:0,
                 from /tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp:29:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/sensor_model.h:33:10: fatal error: gazebo/math/gzmath.hh: No such file or directory
 #include <gazebo/math/gzmath.hh>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7495: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_magnetic.h:37:0,
                 from /tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp:29:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/sensor_model.h:33:10: fatal error: gazebo/math/gzmath.hh: No such file or directory
 #include <gazebo/math/gzmath.hh>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7532: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/all] Error 2
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::~DiffDrivePlugin6W()’:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:68:18: error: ‘DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
   event::Events::DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin(updateConnection);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:98:62: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
     link = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<physics::Link>(world->GetEntity(_sdf->GetElement("bodyName")->Get<std::string>()));
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::Reset()’:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:178:27: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   prevUpdateTime = world->GetSimTime();
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
                           SetSimTime
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::Update()’:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:205:21: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   stepTime = world->GetSimTime() - prevUpdateTime;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
                     SetSimTime
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:206:27: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   prevUpdateTime = world->GetSimTime();
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
                           SetSimTime
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp: In member function ‘void gazebo::DiffDrivePlugin6W::publish_odometry()’:
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:309:35: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   ros::Time current_time_((world->GetSimTime()).sec, (world->GetSimTime()).nsec);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                   SetSimTime
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:309:62: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   ros::Time current_time_((world->GetSimTime()).sec, (world->GetSimTime()).nsec);
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                              SetSimTime
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:312:3: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
   math::Pose pose = link->GetWorldPose();
   ^~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:313:3: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
   math::Vector3 velocity = link->GetWorldLinearVel();
   ^~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:314:3: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
   math::Vector3 angular_velocity = link->GetWorldAngularVel();
   ^~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:316:21: error: ‘pose’ was not declared in this scope
   tf::Quaternion qt(pose.rot.x, pose.rot.y, pose.rot.z, pose.rot.w);
                     ^~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:316:21: note: suggested alternative: ‘pause’
   tf::Quaternion qt(pose.rot.x, pose.rot.y, pose.rot.z, pose.rot.w);
                     ^~~~
                     pause
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:334:32: error: ‘velocity’ was not declared in this scope
   odom_.twist.twist.linear.x = velocity.x;
                                ^~~~~~~~
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:334:32: note: suggested alternative: ‘select’
   odom_.twist.twist.linear.x = velocity.x;
                                ^~~~~~~~
                                select
/tests/simulation_ws/src/tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:336:33: error: ‘angular_velocity’ was not declared in this scope
   odom_.twist.twist.angular.z = angular_velocity.z;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7643: recipe for target 'tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tum_ardrone_sim/tum-simulator-indigo/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344849/invoking-%22make--j4--4%22-in-melodic-failed/) by [pcf3333](https://answers.ros.org/users/52010/pcf3333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just install  sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev

---

Originally posted by [pcf3333](https://answers.ros.org/users/52010/pcf3333/) with karma: 16 on 2020-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0